# Powershell variable scope and temporary files within the context of a VS2015 MSBuild project

Tags: powershell, msbuild

## Question

Two separate Powershell scripts, run from two separate projects (Chrome and Firefox), apparently write to the same temporary file.

This doesn't happen often, apparently once every few months or so. When it does happen, though, the two separate projects each end up with their `manifest.json` and `package.json` files munged together, such that each file will have random lines from the other file interspersed in it.

Any ideas why this occurs?

## Details

I have a VS2015 solution with 25 projects in it. One of the projects is called "Deploy", and has declared dependencies on multiple other projects. The two dependencies of significance to this question are the "ChromeExtension" and "FirefoxAddOn" projects.

Each of these projects contains a build target to set the version information in the appropriate manifest file. Here is the Chrome target:

```
<Target Name="SetVersion">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PowerShellExe>powershell.exe</PowerShellExe>
    <PreBuildScript>$(SolutionDir)powershell\ChromePreBuild.ps1</PreBuildScript>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Exec Command="$(PowerShellExe) -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -command &quot;&amp; { &amp;'$(PreBuildScript)' -solutionDir '$(SolutionDir)\' }&quot;" />
</Target>
```

And the Firefox target is the same except it executes the script, `FirefoxPreBuild.ps1`.

The scripts are relatively simple. The Chrome script:

```
param($solutionDir)

. "${solutionDir}powershell\BuildConfig.ps1"
. "${solutionDir}powershell\ReplaceVersion.ps1"
. "${solutionDir}powershell\ReplaceName.ps1"
. "${solutionDir}powershell\ChromeOptions.ps1"

Write-Host "Performing pre-build actions for Chrome add-on $chromeExtensionVersion"

ReplaceVersion "${solutionDir}ChromeExtension\manifest.json" $chromeExtensionVersion
ReplaceName "${solutionDir}ChromeExtension\manifest.json" "$chromeExtensionName"
```

And the Firefox script:

```
param($solutionDir)

. "${solutionDir}powershell\BuildConfig.ps1"
. "${solutionDir}powershell\ReplaceVersion.ps1"

Write-Host "Performing pre-build actions for Firefox add-on $firefoxExtensionVersion"

ReplaceVersion "${solutionDir}FirefoxAddOn\package.json" $firefoxExtensionVersion
```

The `ReplaceVersion` function, called from both scripts, is pretty ugly, but gets the job done:

```
function ReplaceVersion {
    $file = $args[0]
    $replacementVersion = $args[1]
    Write-Host "- Updating version number in $file to ""$replacementVersion"""
    $tmp = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName();
    if(Test-Path $tmp -PathType Leaf) {
        Remove-Item $tmp
    }
    Get-Content $file | Foreach-Object -process {
        $line = $_
        if ( ($line -match 'AssemblyVersion.*(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)') -or
             ($line -match 'AssemblyFileVersion.*(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)') -or
             ($line -match 'AppFolderName.*(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)') -or
             ($line -match 'SupportedSyncFeatureSetRevision\s*=\s*(\d+);') -or
             ($line -match 'this.AddinName = ".* v(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)";') -or
             ($line -match 'this.Text = ".* v(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)";') -or
             ($line -match '"version":.*"(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.?\d*)"') ) {
             $version = $matches[1]
             $line = $line -replace "$version", "$replacementVersion"
        }
        $line | Add-Content $tmp
    }
    #replace the old file with the new one
    Remove-Item -force $file
    Move-Item $tmp $file -Force -Confirm:$false
}
```

And the `ReplaceName` funcion (Chrome-only) is, unimaginatively and non-DRY, the exact same thing, except with a different pattern to match on:

```
function ReplaceName {
    $file = $args[0]
    $replacementName = $args[1]
    Write-Host "- Updating extension name in $file to ""$replacementName"""
    $tmp = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName();
    if(Test-Path $tmp -PathType Leaf) {
        Remove-Item $tmp
    }
    Get-Content $file | Foreach-Object -process {
        $line = $_
        if ( ($line -match '"name":.*"(.*)"') ) {
             $name = [regex]::escape($matches[1])
             $line = $line -replace "$name", "$replacementName"
        }
        $line | Add-Content $tmp
    }
    #replace the old file with the new one
    Remove-Item -force $file
    Move-Item $tmp $file -Force -Confirm:$false
}
```

Comment: Remove that part from scripts `if(Test-Path $tmp -PathType Leaf) { Remove-Item $tmp }`.

Comment: Ha! Thanks! I bet that's the reason. I don't know why that is in there. It's been like that since the first version of the file, so there's no history for that line of code. I presume this means that `GetTempFileName()` ensures uniqueness based on the contents of the `Temp` directory, and not based on any external source? I won't be able to definitively test to ensure that this is the solution, since the problem happens so infrequently and I don't know how to force it to occur. But I'm pretty sure you are correct. If you want to write up an answer to the question, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove that part from scripts:

```
if(Test-Path $tmp -PathType Leaf) {
    Remove-Item $tmp
}
```

As stated in [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx)

> Creates a uniquely named, zero-byte temporary file on disk and returns the full path of that file.

`[System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()` will create empty file for you, so you does not have to remove and re-create it.

If you look at [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/a.html#3f28ce894873de0a) of `[System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()`, then you can see that it implemented by calling to [`GetTempFileName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa364991.aspx) WinAPI function with `uUnique` equals to zero. Here is relevant part of documentation:

> If `uUnique` is zero, the function attempts to form a unique file name using the current system time. If the file already exists, the number is increased by one and the functions tests if this file already exists. This continues until a unique filename is found; the function creates a file by that name and closes it.

As you can see, `GetTempFileName` use file existence as signal to create different file name. By removing file you open possibility that subsequent call will return the same file name for temporary file.